# How Can I compare the subvalues in a list to eachother using a for-loop?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Currently I have a list such as shown below.  I would like to develop a forloop that goes through each item on the list and compares the characters in that list.  There are never more than two characters in an item.

all = [[a,z]],[[a,a]],[[e,r]],[[p,p]]....(more similar items)]

Also written as:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "z"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "a"

[[3]] 
[1] "e" "r"

[[4]] 
[1] "p" p"
```

I would like to go through each element in the list and test whether the items are the same.  I would like to print the count of items are match.  For example, in this list I would want:

```
[[2]]
 [1] "a" "a"

 [[4]] 
 [1] "p" p"
```

Since "a" matches "a" and "p" matches "p".  I would like the for-loop to return a value of 2, counting the number of matches.

Any suggestions?

Comment: here's one more: `sum(sapply(lst, duplicated))`

Comment: thanks I added it to my benchmark

Answer (score 3):

Using `sapply` with `uniqueN`

```
lst1[sapply(lst1,data.table::uniqueN)==1]
[[1]]
[1] "a" "a"

[[2]]
[1] "p" "p"
```

Comment: Welcome back to R side, Python Pandas guru!

Comment: @Parfait Thanks man , I will try my best to improve my R skill :-)

Comment: it works also with `dplyr::n_distinct` instead of `data.table::uniqueN` and is twice faster with `dplyr` on my computer.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper that is great , thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Filter` to filter the elements of the `list` by creating a logical condition that checks the `length` of `unique` elements in each `list` element as 1

```
out <- Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))==1, lst1)
out
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "p" "p"

length(out)
#[1] 2
```

---

Or another option is

```
sum(sapply(lst1, function(x) do.call(identical, as.list(x))))
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(c('a', 'z'), c('a', 'a'), c('e', 'r'), c('p', 'p'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 more ways :

```
sum((x<-unlist(lst1))[c(T,F)]==x[c(F,T)])
#[1] 2
sum(sapply(lst1,function(x) x[1] == x[2]))
#[1] 2
sum(lengths(sapply(lst1,unique))==1)
#[1] 2
```

And a benchmark:

```
lst2 <- rep(lst1,1000)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mm1 = sum((x<-unlist(lst2))[c(T,F)]==x[c(F,T)]),
  mm2 = sum(sapply(lst2,function(x) x[1] == x[2])),
  mm3 = sum(lengths(sapply(lst2,unique))==1),
  akrun = length(Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))==1, lst2)),
  WB  = length(lst2[sapply(lst2,data.table::uniqueN)==1]),
  WB2 = length(lst2[sapply(lst2,dplyr::n_distinct)==1]),
  dd  = sum(sapply(lst2, duplicated)),
  dd2 = sum(sapply(lst2, function(x) duplicated(x)[2]))
)

# Unit: microseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval    cld
# mm1     146.104   156.972   284.218   160.292   164.368   9357.887   100 a     
# mm2    4141.922  4493.899  5211.921  5043.449  5550.736   8576.352   100  b    
# mm3   15911.727 17504.531 19123.916 19108.955 20324.424  26267.587   100    de 
# akrun 17991.895 19451.122 21222.071 20960.609 22765.172  29885.165   100     e 
# WB    31602.789 36288.222 39258.331 37895.967 39659.628 134526.556   100      f
# WB2   14003.624 15026.653 16783.403 15391.911 16116.695 119739.284   100   c   
# dd    14493.253 15950.668 17077.778 16792.124 17932.125  21876.323   100   cd  
# dd2   16532.970 17768.060 19172.640 18722.867 20769.075  24318.128   100    de
```